# Dropdown Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdown

I have a dropdown, which the select list is generate like this

```
              <select class="form-control" id="edit-role">
                 @foreach($role as $val)
                 <option value="{{$val->id}}">{{$val->display_name}}</option>
                 @endforeach
              </select>
```

But I also want to set selected value from existing data through jQuery

```
$('#edit-role select').val(user.role_id)
```

The selected value from jQuery will show up if 'value' attribute in option is empty, but when I change my option it wont have 'value' because the 'value' is empty.

If 'value' set like `value="{{$val->id}}"` the selected value from jQuery which it is the existing data wont show up.

please enlighten me, thank you

Comment: in 'foreach' check current value == existing value then make it selected

Comment: $('select#edit-role ').val(user.role_id)

Comment: wrap inside setTimeout so, the value is set after page is rendered properly. ;(function(){ $('select#edit-role ').val(user.role_id)})();

Comment: hey it works, it only have to move the position of 'select' hehe.  thank you for helping @AlaksandarJesusGene